# How do i get html do post data through php in a docker container?

Tags: php, html, docker

So i have an HTML form which on click of 'submit' posts input data through to a basic PHP file which takes the data and stores it in a JSON file. I am able to run the index.html file on a PHP webserver with the command `php -S localhost:4040` and on submit, it does as expected. i want to containerise the website. But when I run the website on a docker container, click submit on the form, I get shown '405 Not Allowed' error. i use docker-compose.yml file to get the docker container running. How can I get this working on a docker container?
Snippet of my code.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Registration</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <section>
      <form id="regForm" action="form.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" name="studentName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your full name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="loginInput">Login</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginInput" name="studentId" placeholder="Enter your login">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

echo "<h2>Submitted</h2>";



if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {


$data = '';
$filename = "data.json";
//if file exists
if(is_file($filename)) {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
}

$json_arr = json_decode($data,true);

$json_arr[] = array(
    'studentId' => $_REQUEST['studentId'],
    'studentName' => $_REQUEST['studentName'],
);

//saving file in jsonarray
file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($json_arr));

}

?>
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  product-services:
    build: ./src
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - 5001:80
```

Comment: Please share your nginx.conf file and which endpoint is called for postin data?

Comment: i do not have an nginx.conf file. I'm not sure what you mean by endpoint, but this is how it post <form id="regForm" action="form.php" method="post">